# Max value for the front size does not affect browser font size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure it out how do include the maximum font-size value. Right now, when the Chrome browser font-size is being changed to very large, my text leaves the bounds of the div. I've tried using `clamp` and `min` as a font-size property, but none of them worked.
How do you manage in these situations, when you use `rem` as a size units, but don't want your text to leave the `div` block bounds when the browser text font size is being changed by the user?

```css
.text {
  font-size: min(4rem, 110px);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some Text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use vw (% of the viewport width)

```css
.text {
  font-size: 8vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some Text</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. It scales upon resizing the screen. There is no impact on the text while changing browser default font-size. But what about user experience? What if a user needs to make a text larger?

Comment: than you can gives a static font size for a particular screen.

Comment: Static font size for a particular screen? I'm not talking about screen sizing, I'm talking about browsers font-size scaling

Answer (score 0):

you can use em,rem,%(percentage from parent element's size),VW(view port width) for the font size.
And you can add the text in h elem

```css
.text h1{
  font-size:10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="text"><h1>Some Text</h1></div>
```

Comment: Yes, the solution works fine, but will it impact the user experience, if a user uses bigger browser font-size?

Comment: You are right, em,rem,px are the best units for the font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this using the `сals()` method. The minimum value will be `4rem`, and the font will change when the browser resizes. It works.

```css
.text {
  font-size: calc(4rem + 5vw);
}
```

```html
<div class="text">Some Text</div>
```